# Python: Replace occurrences of items in multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, replace

I have some lists:

```
#list a
a = ['python', 'c++', 'c#', 'c-plus-plus', 'c-sharp', 'csharp', 'cplus']

# list b 
b = ['c++', 'c-plus-plus', 'cplus', 'c-plusplus', 'cplusplus']

# list c
C = ['c#', 'c-sharp', 'csharp']
```

After the replacements, the `list a` must be

```
# list a after replacements
a = ['python', 'cplusplus', 'csharp', 'cplusplus', 'csharp', 'csharp', 'cplusplus']
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of items in `list b` in `list a` with `cplusplus`,

while all the contents of `list c` in `list a` must be replaced with `csharp`

Repetations are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
['cplusplus' if i in b else i for i in a]
```

Output:

> ['python', 'cplusplus', 'c#', 'cplusplus', 'c-sharp', 'csharp', 'cplusplus']

[Demo](https://ideone.com/uoIdpz)

Comment: And then to address his second point, `['csharp' if i in c else i for i in a]`

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Yeah. No need to repeat same code above :)

Answer (score 2):

For your particular problem this will work:

```
def replace_synonyms(target,synonyms):
    """ Replaces all occurences of any word in list target with last element in synonyms """
    return [synonyms[-1] if word in synonyms else word for word in target]
a=replace_synonyms(a,b)
a=replace_synonyms(a,c)
```

Answer (score 1):

sam2090's code was right, but will take two passes for each of `b` and `c`. A way to do it in one pass:

```
['cplusplus' if i in b else 'csharp' if i in c else i for i in a]
```